Npgsql: How to use BeginTextImportAsync?
In the Npgsql API reference (v8) is a method NpgsqlConnection.BeginTextExportAsync described, but I can't  find any example how to use this async variant of the BeginTextExport method.
I use the COPY command for a bulk upload of data rows. The input comes from a StringBuilder and this synchronous code is actually used to write each data row into STDIN:
using var writer = connection.BeginTextImport(_sqlCopyRawData);
foreach (String sLine in sb.ToString().Split(Environment.NewLine))
{
    writer.WriteLine(sLine);
}

I can see, that the NqpsqlConnection uses also for the synchronous method an internal async method (GitHub):
    public TextReader BeginTextExport(string copyToCommand)
        => BeginTextExport(async: false, copyToCommand, CancellationToken.None).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

How could this async method be used?
Thanks,
Mike

Presumably in the same fashion: use the resulting reader to do reader.ReadLine or reader.ReadLineAsync. What did you try?

Oh, sorry, too stupid of me. It seems to me that I somehow tested too much and then overlooked a simple solution. I'll post the answer.

Sorry, it was too simple ...
(seems I was a little bit confused of the using).
using var writer = await connection.BeginTextImportAsync(_sqlCopyDerivedData, cancellationToken);
// use the writer


What does the above code have to do with BeginTextExportAsync?

Thanks for your hint. I removed the unneccessary code.

I still don't get this, it's just a copy of the question

The await before the connection.BeginTextImportAsync was missing in the question!

Like I said, I still don't get it. This is for importing not exporting, as in the question. And if the whole question was just how to use async Task functions, a cursory Google or documentation check could have told you that.
